# Unable to get the Angular editor within the Eclipse AngularJS plugin to work properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, eclipse

I'm running Eclipse Mars on Ubuntu.  Using Tern, PyDev, and AngularJS Eclipse plugins.

When I'm editing an HTML file with angular code, the "ng" attributes are not recognized by the editor.  According to the documentation, it seems that I should be able to hover over an angular directive and the editor should display some context sensitive help but  I get nothing.

The other possibly-relevant symptom, is that on the tab at the top of the edit window, there is a "dg" icon, and not an "A" icon.  According to the documentation, I should see the red Angular "A" icon.  I checked the pull-down for the available editors when opening the file and I see things like Django Editor, HTML Editor, Text Editor, Web Browser, System Editor, Default Editor, JavaScript Editor.  None of these solve the problem.  I don't know if perhaps there should also be an "Angular Editor", but if so, I don't have it.

I've gone through the process of converting the converting the project to an AngularJS project, by right-clicking the project from the Project Explorer, and selecting Configure.  The code seems to behave OK, but I'm just not getting any recognition of the "ng-" terms.  Any ideas?

Comment: the "ng" attributes are not recognized by the editor => is compleion working? If yes, I suppose it's a validation problem https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started#validation

Comment: Actually, completion works only "partially". It will provide prompts when I'm entering the HTML tags, but going further into the completion of the tag syntax, it doesn't suggest anything.  For example, if I start to type a tag "<d", it suggests a "<div", but one I get beyond the "<div", it gives me no help regarding suggesting a class attribute, nor does it recognize that I'm trying to type an angular keyword, such as "ng-show".

Comment: You must use HTML Editor (Angular Editor doesn't exist today). Have you completion inside JavaScript Editor like ang + Ctrl+Space ? (it must shows angular inside completion popup).

Comment: Truly, I'm not sure if I understand what you are asking Angelo.  If I go into the the JavaScript Editor, yes, Ctrl+Space brings up the completion suggestions.  But there are no suggestions for ang.

Comment: It seems that tern doesn't work. Have you a .tern-project in your project root folder?

Comment: No, I don't see a .tern-project.

Comment: If you open the project properties, have you a Tern menu item?

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed the Angular JS plugin, you should have simultaneously installed tern, unless you unchecked all of the tern-related options.  If you did so, uninstall the plugin and reinstall it with these options checked (you most likely need all of them, unless you don't use PHP with Angular, in which case you can skip those options).

After checking this, there are two more things you need to do to get recognition of the "ng-" directives recognized and code completion working in both the HTML and JSP editors (and PHP if you use it):

1. Right-click on the project with which you want to use Angular and make sure you have converted it to an Angular JS project (under the Configure option near the bottom of the list of options).  If it is not listed as an option, you have already converted it.   NOTE: You cannot create a "new" Angular JS project - you have to first create a static or dynamic web project and then convert it to an Angular JS project using this method.
2. Right-click on the project again, and this time select "Properties", at the bottom.  When the project properties are displayed, then expand the "Validation" option and click on "HTML Syntax".  Be sure to check the checkbox for "Enable project-specific settings" at the top of the resulting display. Under the following area for "Selecting the severity level for the following...", collapse the Elements section (the first section, which will probably be expanded by default), and expand the "Attributes" section immediately below it.  Set the behavior for the first option, "Undefined attribute name", to "Ignore".  Click "OK", restart Eclipse, and the editors should now recognize and do code-completion for Angular directives.  Good luck.  Angular is great stuff, especially once you get Eclipse totally on-board with it.

Question:  Why couldn't the Angular JS installer be made to handle these finicky details?